# how to upload a image in firebase storage and update the link in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm tryin to upload a image to the Firebase storage and download the url and update it to Firestore but i cant able to upload .

```
 const uploadData = async () => {
    if (loading) return;

    setLoading(true);

    // Upload the image blob to Firebase Storage
    const response = await fetch(image.uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    console.log(blob);
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `users/${uid}/profile-image`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, blob);

    // Get the download URL of the uploaded image
    let downloadURL;
    try {
      const snapshot = await uploadTask;
      downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    // Update the user document in Firestore with the download URL
    const userDocRef = doc(firestore, "users", uid, "userdetails");
    try {
      await updateDoc(userDocRef, {
        name: name,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        profileImageURL: downloadURL,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Comment: Any error? Is the file correctly uploaded? Also, with `doc(firestore, "users", uid, "userdetails")`you'll create a doc in the `userdetails`subcollection. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If so can you share by editing question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this blog](https://dev.to/adii9/uploading-images-to-firebase-storage-in-react-native-with-expo-workflow-24kj) for reference.

This [repo](https://github.com/adii9/Image-Upload-to-Firebase) is using similar logic for uploading the image to firebase storage.